# Update values into XML in ORACLE 10G

Tags: oracle

I have below XML in folder, i want to find and replace some values. How to do that?

Example: Wherever UK0 is there i want to replace UK1 using UPDATE QUERY.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RSET>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868001.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK0</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868002.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK0</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
</RSET>
```

Answer (score 0):

In 10g you can use [the `updatexml()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm):

```
select updatexml(your_xml, '/RSET/ROW/SDC_TO[text()="UK0"]/text()', 'UK1')
from ...
```

Demo (run in 11gR2 to use the `indent` clause of `xmlserialize()`, just to make it prettier; the `updatexml()` part works in 10gR2):

```
select xmlserialize(content
  updatexml(xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RSET>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868001.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK0</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868002.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
</RSET>'), '/RSET/ROW/SDC_TO[text()="UK0"]/text()', 'UK1')
    indent) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RSET>
  <ROW>
    <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868001.XML</SDC_FNAME>
    <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
    <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
    <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
    <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
    <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
    <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868002.XML</SDC_FNAME>
    <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
    <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
    <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
    <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
    <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
    <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
  </ROW>
</RSET>
```

---

That function is deprecated in later version, so <strike>(assuming this works in 10g, which I can't verify right now)</strike> from 11g you should use XQuery instead:

```
select xmlquery('
  copy $i := $p modify (
    for $j in $i/RSET/ROW/SDC_TO[text()="UK0"]
      return replace value of node $j with "UK1"
    )
    return $i'
  passing your_xml AS "p"
  returning content)
from ...
```

but that syntax isn't supported in 10gR2.

Demo anyway (run under 11gR2):

```
select xmlserialize(content xmlquery('
  copy $i := $p modify (
    for $j in $i/RSET/ROW/SDC_TO[text()="UK0"]
      return replace value of node $j with "UK1"
    )
    return $i'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RSET>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868001.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK0</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868002.XML</SDC_FNAME>
  <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
  <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
  <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
  <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
  <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
  <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
 </ROW>
</RSET>') AS "p"
  returning content) indent) as result
from dual;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RSET>
  <ROW>
    <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868001.XML</SDC_FNAME>
    <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
    <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
    <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
    <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
    <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
    <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <SDC_FNAME>JQ13868002.XML</SDC_FNAME>
    <SDC_RECORD>6</SDC_RECORD>
    <SDC_FROMDT>06/14/2017 08:13:58</SDC_FROMDT>
    <SDC_TODT>06/16/2017 08:13:58</SDC_TODT>
    <SDC_TNAME>S_STYLE</SDC_TNAME>
    <SDC_FROM>AB</SDC_FROM>
    <SDC_TO>UK1</SDC_TO>
  </ROW>
</RSET>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use .bat(batch file)

Comment: @dkoothan - you can have a batch file run a script via SQL\*Plus. There are lots of examples around.  Presumably you're loading the XML into Oracle at some point (or why involve Oracle here at all?) so this can be used to update a value already in a table, with `update your_table set your_xml = updatexml(your_xml, ...)`. If the XML isn't in the database yet then you could look at SQL\*Loader or [external tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm). Trying to insert a value of more than 4k through a batch script is a bit of a pain.